# How to customize colors in blueprintjs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, blueprintjs

Right now what [blueprint](http://blueprintjs.com/)'s main css file has some classes like `pt-intent-primary, pt-intent-success, pt-intent-warning;` etc. i want to change the default colors of some of these classes. Should i import its source .scss file in my code(if Yes How?) or should i build separately a .css file from .scss file given and then use it.

Answer (score 17):

[This Github issue thread](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/123) provides some good information about how to customize Blueprint's colors. In short, you should import blueprint's Sass source after changing all the color variables you need.

```
$pt-intent-primary: blue;

@import "~@blueprintjs/core/src/blueprint.scss";
```

Comment: Default style is greyscale. can i change it to blue with minimal code? else i have write pt-intent-primary on every element class attribute.